# Get result from response in ajax-function

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

How do I fetch the data in the response-variable. In the debugger I can see all the data sent back (image) but how do I fetch the information from Object?

```
function getUserList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            name: "paul rudd",
            movies: ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"]
        },
        success: function(response) {

            console.log(response);

        }
    });

}
```

I am following the example at

https://reqres.in/

[image]

Comment: Use `console.log(response.variableName)`. Where `variableName` will be your variable what you sent in your `data` and let me know if it works.

Comment: @AnkitSingh - thanks it works good but when it comes to accessing movies which is an array it wont work. If I try with response.movies[0] for instance I get an "uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 0 of undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Create an global variable in required format and assign ajax post value to it. But make sure object properties first then create the object. Otherwise you need to extent it by using jquery [extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method

```
var userObject = {createdAt:"",id:"",movies:[],name:""};

function getUserList() {

$.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: "paul rudd",
        movies: ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"]
    },
    success: function(response){
        userObject = response;
        console.log(userObject.createdAt+" "+ userObject.id);

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks - but how do I fetch content of the movies-variable.? Tried with userObject.movies[0] for the first indexposition

Comment: Use the same logic. Create a movies object and access movies array with help of that object.